# IE9 Developer Toolbar XML5602: Unexpected end of input

Tags: internet-explorer

Developer Toobar throws me `XML5602: Unexpected end of input. , line 1 character 175`, but I can't refer to place where issue occurs. 
How to debug an errors like that?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It could also be in your stylehseet! referencing an SVG style that your web environment does not like.  I had the following SVG background associated to a "form" element in my SharePoint environment...

The CSS:

```
.my-button {
background: url("data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiA/Pgo8c3ZnIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgd2lkdGg9IjEwMCUiIGhlaWdodD0iMTAwJSIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDEgMSIgcHJlc2VydmVBc3BlY3RSYXRpbz0ibm9uZSI+CiAgPGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkLXVjZ2ctZ2VuZX");

background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #eeeeee 0%, #ffffff 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#eeeeee), color-stop(100%,#ffffff));
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #eeeeee 0%,#ffffff 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #eeeeee 0%,#ffffff 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #eeeeee 0%,#ffffff 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #eeeeee 0%,#ffffff 100%);
}
```

And the moment I took out that svg+xml line, IE was back to normal.  Hope this helps someone out, especially if you do a lot of front-end coding like myself.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reproduce this problem by opening an unvalid xml file. This is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <value example="true" />
```

In the above example I "forget" to close the .

If you open this in your browser you won't get this error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <value example="true" />
</root>
```

**In short: You forgot to close a tag somewhere!**